# Setting cucumber-jvm format options in Maven to append all test execution results

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm

The question is regarding the cucumber format option in maven:

In every Junit I have something like:

```
@Cucumber.Options(format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report/foo" })
```

I added the following option to the pom file:

```
  <properties>
    <cucumber.options> --format html:target/cucumber-html-report/allFoos</cucumber.options>     
  </properties>
```

The generated report only have the last execution.

Is there a way to do an "append"?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the report to have multiple test runs? or just the output of multiple tests? edit: just saw this is from march.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that when cucumber runs a junit runner file it opens or creates the specified html report file you reference in the runner file. Since cucumber has no idea what each and every test runner plans on writing to when it runs, it overwrites the file if it is used by multiple test runners. There is no append that you could add to have all of your test runs write to a single file. Your best option (and best practice) is to have each junit test runner write to an individual file, with a name that is descriptive of what the test suite is testing.